# Understanding probability in perudo game

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to understand the probability calculation of perudo game given in the following site (https://boardgamestrategy.blog/2017/03/27/perudo-liars-dice/), under heading "Play the probablities", it says that on average a "6" appearing in 15 other dice rolls is $\frac{1}{6} * 15$. Shouldn't it be $\frac{1}{6^{15}}$ ?.

Comment: I don't think that it says it is the probability that the $6$ should appear on all dice rolls, rather it is the average number of sixes across the $15$ dice rolls.

Comment: They are indeed speaking of expectation.  Out of $15$ dice, we expect $5$ to be either $6$ or $1$ ($1's$, I gather, being wild cards).  Not crazy to bet accordingly.  Of course, you can be more precise if you wish and compute the probabilities exactly.  That's not too difficult and gives more detailed information.

Comment: To stress:  while this situation is quite simple, there are other situations in which betting on expectation is risky.  Take something that pays of $0$ with probability $.999$ but which pays a million with probability $.001$   That has expected payout of $1000$ but a very low chance of winning anything.